# Why does this Xor seem to have a limit?

Tags: vb.net

I use `Xor` as a simple security fence for my app. The string stringdate could, in time, be quite long, up to 600 characters, but at present there seems to be a size limit. The code below errors if the string length exceeds 318.

The error is

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Are there any limits on array size etc. that could cause this?

```vb
Dim c() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringdate)
For i = 0 To c.Length - 1
    c(i) = c(i) Xor (256 * Rnd()) '<<<<< The code Errors here
    'Debug.Print(".NET  c(" & i & ") = " & c(i))
Next
IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Filename, c)
```

Comment: The error suggests that there is an issue with something going out of range (most likely out of range for `Byte`).  The effect of the string length is likely to only be that it got you to the point in the random sequence where the random number triggered the overflow.  I would recommend to assign the result of `Rnd()` to a temporary and print that, it may give you insight into what went wrong.

Comment: What is `Rnd()` returning? Change 256 in 255. Probably better use the Random class (if that's a random number), as `Xor CByte(255 * [Random].NextDouble())`. Do you have Option Strict set to `ON`?

Comment: What would you expect as a result if `Rnd()` returns 1.0 (or a number like 0.99 which is close enough to 1.0 such that `256 * Rnd()` rounds to 256)?

Comment: Many thanks for all the responses. It was the fact that my Rnd()  (not truely random) produced 0,9999 on the 319th call. So I will implement the suggestions to limit this.

Comment: One fix would have been to use `Math.Floor(256 * Rnd())` because Rnd() never produces exactly 1. But System.Random is a better random number generator. The [RandomNumberGenerator Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator) is even better, if you need that.

Answer (score -1):

Put this at the top of your code file, and it won't even let you run that code in the first place.

```vb
Option Strict On
```

You are trying to do implicit conversions which is risky especially when you could have 256 as your max value, which does not fit into a byte. Use `CByte` to make sure the random value is a byte to be Xor'ed with.

You should use 255 instead of 256 so all values resulting from the `Xor` will fit into a byte. With your code as it is, there is a 1/256 chance that your randomized number won't fit into a byte.

The `Rnd()` function is not the correct one to use as you will consistently get the same "random" values when you run your application because you aren't calling `Randomize()` But still, use the framework `System.Random` class instead of VB6 holdovers whenever possible.

Interestingly (I think so), this claim

> The code below errors if the string length exceeds 318

is based on the fact that you aren't randomizing first, so you are always getting the same random number train. The number 318 is not special other than the fact that in your application, the 318th random number is greater than `1 - 1 / 256`, resulting in an overflow. You can test this by calling `Randomize()` and you will get an exception at a different place, or not at all.

Anyway, your code can be changed to this

```vb
Dim c() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringdate)
Dim r = New System.Random()
For i = 0 To c.Length - 1
    c(i) = c(i) Xor CByte(r.Next(255))
Next
```

Or done all in the same line

```vb
Dim r = New System.Random()
Dim c = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringdate).Select(Function(b) b Xor CByte(r.Next(255))).ToArray()
```

Comment: @Craig, you can write your own answer with your own wording, but don't change mine. I worded it as I intended. You could even write a comment here. Thanks!

Comment: If you want a whole number in the range 0-255, I would think that using `r.Next(256)` would be a better option that using `NextDouble`. You could even use `NextBytes` with a `Byte` array with one element and get a `Byte` directly.

Comment: @jmcilhinney true, updated the answer

Comment: @djv I disagree with the way you originally worded it.  It's not clear what you mean by "consistently get the same random values".  Since answers are meant to be a community resource and I didn't think I was fundamentally changing the meaning of what you said, I thought it was appropriate (and within the usage guidelines of SO) to make the edit.

Comment: @Craig I think everything is clear in the question. But thanks for the input